# Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token exception received in Wiremock Json file configuration

Tags: java, wiremock

I am trying to mock few API's using `WireMock` standalone jar with `JSON` file configuration.

Below is the `JSON` file containing multiple stub mappings which I'm using-

```
{
  "mappings": [{
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/users"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "body": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Leanne Graham",
            "username": "Bret",
            "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
            "address": {
              "street": "Kulas Light",
              "suite": "Apt. 556",
              "city": "Gwenborough",
              "zipcode": "92998-3874",
              "geo": {
                "lat": "-37.3159",
                "lng": "81.1496"
              }
            },
            "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
            "website": "hildegard.org",
            "company": {
              "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
              "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
              "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
            }
          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Ervin Howell",
            "username": "Antonette",
            "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
            "address": {
              "street": "Victor Plains",
              "suite": "Suite 879",
              "city": "Wisokyburgh",
              "zipcode": "90566-7771",
              "geo": {
                "lat": "-43.9509",
                "lng": "-34.4618"
              }
            },
            "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
            "website": "anastasia.net",
            "company": {
              "name": "Deckow-Crist",
              "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
              "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
            }
          }
        ],

        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/posts?userId=1"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "body": "[]"
      }
    },
    {
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/comments?postId=1"
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "body": "[]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I am trying to start `Wiremock` server using standalone jar (`wiremock-standalone-2.24.1.jar`) I am getting below exception, I verified the Json schema and it looks ok.

> Wiremock msrivast$ java -jar wiremock-standalone-2.24.1.jar Exception
>   in thread "main"
>   com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.MappingFileException: Error
>   loading file
>   /Users/msrivast/Downloads/Wiremock/./mappings/results.json: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token
>     at
>   com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.JsonFileMappingsSource.loadMappingsInto(JsonFileMappingsSource.java:121)
>     at
>   com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockApp.loadMappingsUsing(WireMockApp.java:199)
>     at
>   com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockApp.loadDefaultMappings(WireMockApp.java:195)
>     at
>   com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockApp.(WireMockApp.java:103)
>     at
>   com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.(WireMockServer.java:72)
>     at
>   com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner.run(WireMockServerRunner.java:65)
>     at
>   com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner.main(WireMockServerRunner.java:125)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**body** parameter always expects a String in WireMock. It worked once I passed my response in body as a String.

Answer (score 6):

Based on code base: https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/http/ResponseDefinition.java

The **body** key in your response definition can be `body`, `jsonBody`, `base64Body` or `null`

Answer (score 1):

The key "**body**" in the object "**response**" only accepts a string.
You can replace the key "**body**" with the key "**jsonBody**" if you wanna pass a JSON to it.